# How select under documents via $in operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want grab all under documents via Id's like the following SQL query:

```
Select * from table 
where subdoc1.id in (1234, 2345, 3456) 
  or subdoc2.id in (1234, 2345, 3456)
```

Here is the structure of my document:

```
{ 
  "id" : new ObjectId("234565"),
  "subdocs1" : [ {
                   "id" : "1234",
                   ... },
                 {
                   "id": "2345",
                   ... }],
   "subdocs2"  : [ {
                   "id" : "3456",
                   ... },
                 {
                   "id": "7890",
                   ... }]
}
```

How would the query look like in MongoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
$and : [{"subdocs1._id": {"$in" : ["1234", "2345", "3456"]},
{"subdocs2._id": {"$in" : ["1234", "2345", "3456"]}}]
})
```

OR

```
db.collection.find({
$and : [{"subdocs1":{"$elemMatch" : {"$_id" : {"$in" : ["1234", "2345", "3456"]}}}},
{"subdocs2:{"$elemMatch" : {"$_id" : {"$in" : ["1234", "2345", "3456"]}}}}]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my query, that works:

```
db.getCollection('documents').find({
$or : [
    { "subdoc1._id" : { "$in" : [ new ObjectId("5807a60afc84c80a5ea86218"), new ObjectId("5808ac5cfc841deda17f827b") ] } },
    { "subdoc2._id" : { "$in" : [ new ObjectId("5807a60afc84c80a5ea86218"), new ObjectId("5808ac5cfc841deda17f827b") ] } },
    { "subdoc3._id" : { "$in" : [ new ObjectId("5807a60afc84c80a5ea86218"), new ObjectId("5808ac5cfc841deda17f827b") ] } },
    { "subdoc4._id" : { "$in" : [ new ObjectId("5807a60afc84c80a5ea86218"), new ObjectId("5808ac5cfc841deda17f827b") ] } }
]})
```

Thanx!!